# Android shopping cart : How to keep products when user exit from app?

Tags: android

I'm developing an e-commerce application like flipkart or amazon , i need to keep the products in the cart even if user accidentally exits from app and iam following tutorial
http://www.androiddom.com/2011/06/android-shopping-cart-tutorial-part-2.html
 can anybody tell me how to store products even after exiting from the app ?

Comment: Go through the options here and choose for yourself. https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html

Answer (score 5):

> Android provides several options for you to save persistent application data. The solution you choose depends on your specific needs, such as whether the data should be private to your application or accessible to other applications (and the user) and how much space your data requires.

Your data storage options are the following, but for your specific case i would go for Shared Preferences:

- Shared Preferences

  Store private primitive data in key-value pairs.
- Internal Storage

  Store private data on the device memory.
- External Storage

  Store public data on the shared external storage.
- SQLite Databases

  Store structured data in a private database.
- Network Connection

  Store data on the web with your own network server.

Answer (score 2):

1. You can use shared preference to store local cart data.
2. Also, SQLITE db is another option to store users cart data.

Answer (score 1):

To store data you would typically use a Database. Personally I would recommend Realm as a local database for Android given it's simplicity and good documentation

Comment: MacLean Sochor Thanks for this suggestion m looking forward to realm

Answer (score 0):

You can use a SQLite database.

Here's an [official documentation](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/databases.html).

Answer (score 0):

You can use a database (SQLite) or use a sharedpreferences key with a string of the selected products

You can use sharedpreferences like so:

```
PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(getApplicationContext()).edit().putString("cartporducts","porduct1;porduct2;porduct3;porduct4;...").apply();
```

Comment: You will store 100 products with keys `product1name`, `product1qty`, `product2name`, `product2qty`... No, that's not very good approach.

Comment: @sudo yes, you are right with 100 products, but i never have more than 10 products in the cart

Comment: Yes, but it is a easy way to save data with out create a db or is there a simple better way that I don't now?

Comment: If OP wants to make *`an e-commerce application like flipkart or amazon`*, he would need to use SQLite or at least **not** `SharedPreferences`.

Comment: @sudo Why not SharedPreferences?  It's just a different way of writing data to a file.  For such a small amount of data it seems manageable.

Comment: @nasch **1.** You will not be able to search or perform complex queries with `SharedPreferences`. **2.** You need a separate entry for storing currently not deleted item's ids. **⋅** It's your **preference** to choose what suits for you.

Comment: While that is true, this is not an inventory database; the use case is to save and restore the state of a shopping cart.